# transmission crashing and data loss

Tags: 12.04, unity, drivers, transmission

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2109152

This is happening to me, in the sense that transmission is freezing, I have to force quit, and I lose all data downloaded since it was launched.  It's very annoying.

It's some sort of unity problem, it affects other windows--transmission is just the most annoying one it happens to.

This guy's thread never got answered after a year--I hope I don't have to wait that long.
I blame compiz.  Other distros have tossed it and ubuntu needs to get on board.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to that occasional issue was to replace Transmission with Deluge, which is more featureful and seems to be more solid.